# TagBar plugin cannot be added using ctags

Tags: vim, groovy, tagbar

I'm trying to get the vim TagBar plugin to work with groovy language.
I'm running on a Debian Linux. I've installed exhuberant-ctags.

I've searched on the web and found those two sites:

- https://github.com/majutsushi/tagbar/issues/84
- https://github.com/majutsushi/tagbar/wiki#groovy

So I created a `~/.ctags` file containing

```
--langdef=groovy
--langmap=groovy:.groovy
--regex-groovy=/^[ \t][(private|public|protected) ( \t)][A-Za-z0-9<>]+[ \t]+([A-Za-z0-9]+)[ \t](.)[ \t]{/\1/f,function,functions/
--regex-groovy=/^[ \t]*def[ \t]+([A-Za-z0-9_]+)[ \t]\=[ \t]{/\1/f,function,functions/
--regex-groovy=/^[ \t]*private def[ \t]+([A-Za-z0-9_]+)[ \t]/\1/v,private,private variables/
--regex-groovy=/^[ \t]def[ \t]+([A-Za-z0-9_]+)[ \t]/\1/u,public,public variables/
--regex-groovy=/^[ \t][abstract ( \t)][(private|public) ( \t)]class[ \t]+([A-Za-z0-9_]+)[ \t]/\1/c,class,classes/
--regex-groovy=/^[ \t][abstract ( \t)][(private|public) ( \t)]enum[ \t]+([A-Za-z0-9_]+)[ \t]/\1/c,class,classes/
```

And I've added this at the end of my .vimrc file:

```
let g:tagbar_type_groovy = {
    \ 'ctagstype' : 'groovy',
    \ 'kinds'     : [
        \ 'p:package',
        \ 'c:class',
        \ 'i:interface',
        \ 'f:function',
        \ 'v:variables',
    \ ]
\ }
```

But when I restart vim and edit a file with a simple class, I don't see anything in tagbar. Just the first line "press  for help".

Does anybody knows why I can't manage to have it work?

Thanks

Comment: That identical setup works for me (on Windows). Please ensure that no other ctags implementation is actually called by TagBar, and try generating a tags file for a Groovy file manually on the command-line.

Comment: Also, make sure that the filetype is recognized correctly by Vim. Execute `:set filetype?` and check whether it reports `groovy`.

Comment: Filetype groovy is well recognized by Vim. But I don't really know how to use ctags. I just know it is a dependency for tagbar... When running ctags on a groovy file, a "tags" file is created, but it doesn't contain anything but some header information (_TAG_FILE_FORMAT, etc...). It seems that my ~/.ctags is read. I added some regex error into it and had some warnings from ctags.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to run ctags, inside or outside of Vim. You must check than the generated tags file is correct.

In my .vimrc, I've created the following mapping :

```
map <F5> :!ctags -R
```

to easily run ctags.